# Unable to run script in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use ansible to run homebrew. I am at the stage where my homebrew is installed properly. I need to just configure the path for brew.

Because the without the path the `brew command not found`.

I am following this:

https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux

I am trying to add the following commands into ansible.

```
test -d ~/.linuxbrew && eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
test -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
test -r ~/.bash_profile && echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >>~/.bash_profile
echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >>~/.profile
```

Ansible:

```
- name: map 1
  shell: test -d ~/.linuxbrew && eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

Error:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "test -d ~/.linuxbrew && eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)", "delta": "0:00:00.002858", "end": "2020-07-14 16:44:20.881614", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-07-14 16:44:20.878756", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Comment: I'd guess the `ansible_user`'s home directory isn't the same home directory as when you ran those commands by hand. The `exit 1` is the exit code when the `test -d` failed; if the `test -d` is **expected** to fail, then you'll need either `|| true` in that `shell:` or to add `ignore_errors: yes` to the task

Answer (score 0):

After much testing, I found out this has to do with the user account used.

My base ansible scripts by default was set to `root`. So what I need to do is to set the `become_user: ec2-user` when my `become: no`

```
- name: Test homebrew directive and eval homebrew path
  become: no
  shell: test -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
  become_user: ec2-user
```